# httpUrlconnection returning 500 error code to any call

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, httpurlconnection

my android code to call php webservice (json) on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk returning error code 500, but getErrorStream return correct return of my service.

When i call getInputStream i receive error IOException, but URL is correct and when i call with browser return is correct.

my code:

```
public class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Activity activity;

    public AsyncLogin(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String urlx = url[0];
            URL urlNet = new URL(urlx);
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) urlNet.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            int resposta = conn.getResponseCode();

            InputStream retorno = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(retorno));


            String linha = "";
            while ((linha=br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                resultado.append(linha);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultado.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){
        if (Boolean.valueOf(resultado))
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = array(
    'Teste' => 'Alo mundo!'  
    );

    $resultado = json_encode($data);

    echo $resultado;
?>
```

Comment: 500 error is server side. would you please put the `stacktrace` log

Comment: In onPostExecute you should Toast `resultado`. Now you see nothing.

Comment: A GET with content type application/json? Whers is the json?

Comment: 500 error is server side, but when i call this with browser works fine.

Comment: I try this with POST and GET but not works fine

Comment: I only test value of resultado, but this value is null. When i call getinputstream this code goes to catch ioexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PHP have a error on last code line, when i see on webbrowser phpcode print my json without display error, but last line generate error code 500 and when i call with Android the correct error code is 500.

I solve last line (close connection) with my php and this code works fine.